Showing how RG generates new interactions in Ising
The first answer of this question really enlighted me:
Generating nonlinearities in renormalization group
Is there a way to mathematically show, as it did for the last case, how a blocking procedures generates new kind of interactions? Reading Cardy, I only see that the new Hamiltonian has a new $S'_{i} S'_{i+1}$ term, but it's not a new kind of interaction, as the lattice has defined new $S'$ sites and this is again a nearest neighbor interaction.
Section 4.3 instead adds a new kind of interaction and treats it with relevant or irrilevant agruments.
What was done in that first answer was instead to prove that there was an infinite series of $(x^{2})^{a}$ with $a>0$ terms. I'm looking for something similar with Ising.
The second answer seems to address this issue, but I don't understand how, in equations, what he said actually happens

But you are talking about Ising model.  When $S_i = \pm 1$ only, there really aren't many possibilities.  You can write down any crazy function, but at the end it will only take two possible values.  Everything is equivalent to $S_{i}S_{i+1}$.

Yeah, but Cardy says that even further interaction are enabled, so I expected $S'{i} S'{i+2}$ and further terms to pop up

Which Cardy book and what part of the book?

Page 33 of Scaling and Renormalization in Statistical Physics, above eq. 3.5

I would suggest you keep reading. If memory serves Cardy does explain this more later in the chapter

I found something in section 4.3. Before that I found nothing addressing that issue. However I don't really understand well that section. For what I've understood it just adds a term and says whether it's relevant or irrelevant. For what I understand of relevancy, considering we flow from the UV to the IR, it just adds that: if we have that term in the UV, there is a change it remains in he IR and there is another chance it becomes neglegible. There is nothing of the sort of: If you go in he IR, a neglegible UV term pops up. The only way I think it could be possible is that it has a very small

Coupling constant in the UV, but it's relevant, so that it increases in coupling in the IR. Maybe that's what I was looking for

My main concern is that, differently from what cardy says, if there is only 1 term, that term has a flow. Stop. No other terms involved. If we start with OTHERS terms with small couplings, neglected cause they are small, not zero, than we can have different terms popping up in the IR. But this applies only if those terms exist in the first place

He explains how to generate a next nearest neighbor coupling in 2d with fig 3.8, though I believe that term should die away as you keep going to larger scale.

Thanks! Anyway that means that in 1 dimension is wrong (not overkill) to account for additional terms, while in 2+D it's the only right choice (without renormalization) to account for them. Is there a criterion to understand when you need to account for them, or do I just always add them, as it may not change anything?

A pedagogical paper by Maris and Kadanoff  provides a convincing argument to explain why a coarse-graining procedure may generate new couplings in more than 1D (you can look for it with Google, and you'll probably find a free copy of the PDF).
I'll summarize the argument, making some derivation steps more explicit.
A possible coarse-graining of an initial Ising Hamiltonian ($\cal H $) corresponds to a partial trace over the spins, summing the values of one spine over two. For example, in 1D, one can define a renormalized Hamiltonian ($\cal H' $) by the condition
$$
exp(-\beta \cal H'(\{ odd~site~spins\})) =\sum_{\{ even~site~spins\}} exp(-\beta \cal H(\{ all~spins\})).\tag{1}
$$
In order to get ($\cal H'$) satisfying equation ($1$), one needs to cast every term like
$
\sum_{S_2} exp(K (S_1 S_2 + S_2 S_3)) 
$
in the form of a Boltzmann factor (here $K=-\beta J$, where $J$ is the nearest neighbor coupling constant). In 1D, one can do it by introducing an analytic function $f(K)$ and a new coupling $K'$ such that
$$
\sum_{S_2} exp(K (S_1 S_2 + S_2 S_3)) = f(K)exp(K' S_1 S_3).\tag{2}
$$
By listing the four possible values of $S_1$ and $S_2$, one can check that condition ($2$) results in only two independent equations providing an explicit form for $f(K)$ and $K'(K)$. Thus, in 1D, the proposed coarse-graining transforms a nearest-neighbor Ising Hamiltonian into another Hamiltonian of the same form (but with a renormalized coupling). Notice that, following Maris and Kadanoff, I have written the previous formulas in the absence of an external magnetic field, but its introduction is trivial and doesn't change the conclusion.
Let's look at the two-dimensional case (a similar argument holds for any dimension higher than 1). For simplicity, let's use a square lattice.
Again, we may introduce a coarse-graining corresponding to tracing down one spin over two, like in the following picture (sites with a cross are traced down by summing over their values). For simplicity, the relevant sites have been numbered from $1$ to $5$.

The partial trace over spin $5$ involves the Boltzmann factors of the first neighbor interactions between the pair of sites ($1$,$5$), ($2$,$5$), ($3$,$5$), and ($4$,$5$):
$$
\sum_{S_5} exp(K (S_1 S_5 + S_2 S_5 + S_3 S_5 + S_4 S_5))
$$
It cannot be written as a new nearest-neighbor interaction in the new lattice rotated by 45 degrees because the partial trace depends on four spin values, and the resulting independent equations (four) are more than the two unknown represented by a function $f(K)$ and the new nearest neighbor coupling $K'$. Indeed, reference to the picture shows that the elimination of the spin site $5$ should correspond to three interaction terms:

nearest-neighbor interactions between sites ($1,2$), ($2,3)$, ($3,4$), ($4,1$);
second-neighbor interactions between sites ($1,3$), ($2,4$);
a four-site interaction between the four sites ($1,2$,$3,4$), corresponding to a quartic term: $K'_4 S_1 S_2 S_3 S_4$.

The resulting four independent equations can now determine the three corresponding coupling constants and the factor $f(K)$. Generalization to different lattices or dimensionality is conceptually trivial.

Strictly speaking, even in 1D, you will generate infinitely many coupling terms, all the way to infinite range, after one single step of blocking transformation.
The blocking procedure is supposed to generate an effective model that exact reproduces the same thermodynamics (up to coarse graining).  Normally at this point, the textbook will tell you that you just need to match the free energy.  That is one condition to be satisfied, and determines one parameter (NN coupling) in the coarse-grained model.
However, if you want to stick to the letters of the goal (same thermodynamics), you need to match all correlation functions too.  For example, if your blocking procedure is the majority rule:
$$
S' = \text{sign}(\sum_{block} S),
$$
you can certainly calculate $\langle S'_{i} S'_{i+1} \rangle$ using the initial model.  And then there are $\langle S'_{i} S'_{i+n} \rangle$ for all $n$.  As a rule, you need the nth-neighbor coupling term to match the nth-neighbor correlation.  So, just after one blocking step, you get them all.
But this doesn't matter.  If the model is not critical, all correlation functions decay exponentially as distance increases.  Suppose the correlation length is 10 lattice spacings after the blocking step.  Granted, you technically need the 1000th-neighbor term to fix the 1000th-neighbor correlation, but the wrong value, the right value, and the correction term are all of the order $O(e^{-100})$ anyway.
In practice, we draw the important distinction of whether the coupling term is relevent.  A relevant term hangs around or even gets bigger as you go to larger and larger scale, and we keep it in the effective theory.  An irrelevant term, while it does get created if absent, generally gets small in the large scale limit, and we ignore it.
--edit--
Actually I am not really sure if you get long-range coupling.  Higher order coupling (product of 2n spins for n > 1) now seems more likely to me, as you try to fit 2n spin correlation functions.
Bottom line is, you will definitely generate (a little bit of) junks of all sort.  Most of that will then wash away as you go further.
